# How to infer keys of a generic subtype of a class?

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

I'm trying to create a class that properly infers the keys of a protected class member.

```js
type NodeSchema = { input: Record<string, number> };

class Node<Schema extends NodeSchema> {
  protected readonly input: Schema['input'];

  public constructor(input: Schema['input']) {
    this.input = input;
  }

  public getInput<K extends keyof Schema['input']>(key: K): Schema['input'][K] {
    return this.input[key];
  }
}


const node = new Node({ foo: 1 });
node.getInput(''); // does not infer keys correctly
```

If I replace the complex type NodeSchema with a simplified type argument, the keys are inferred correctly.

```js
class Node<I extends Record<string, number>> {
  protected readonly input: I;

  public constructor(input: I) {
    this.input = input;
  }

  public getInput<K extends keyof I>(key: K): I[K] {
    return this.input[key];
  }
}


const node = new Node({ foo: 1 });
node.getInput('foo'); // infers the key correctly
```

Is there a way to get the first example to work, where the subtype collections for input and output can be properly introspected in various class signatures?

Comment: How does it infer Schema there?

Comment: I think you should explain more what you're trying to do. Why not just use the second code since it works?

Comment: ① The inference you're trying to get in the first version is not supported in TS (unless [ms/TS#53017](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/53017) or the like gets merged).  If that fully addresses the question I'll write up an answer. If not, what am I missing? ② I also want to understand why you're asking for this. The only property you could hope to infer is `input`, so why not just have that property be the type parameter as in the second version? What do you stand to gain from the first version?